# Why I can't use printk() to print string to the screen

Tags: operating-system, linux

I am trying to add some system interface made by myself to Linux-0.11 and using bochs to debug the interface.But I have found two strange things. Here is my code.

```
#include <asm/segment.h>
char msg[24] = {0};//23 characters + ’\0' = 24
int sys_iam(const char* name)
/***
 * function : put the content in name(address) to msg, and the length of it should be no longer than 23  
 * return：the number of character which is copied
 ***/
{
    printk("Sys_iam is running\n");
    int i;
    //store the data temporarily
    char buf[25] = {0};
    for(i = 0;i<25;i++){
        buf[i] = get_fs_byte(name + i);
        if(buf[i] == '\0')break;
    }
    int len = i;
    //if the length is bigger than 23
    if(len > 23){
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;//set the errno to ENIVAL，return -1
    }
    //int j;
    int j;
    for(j = 0;j<len;j++){
        msg[j] = buf[j];
    }
    msg[len] = '\0';
    printk("len:%d\n", len);
    //printk("buflen:%d\n",strlen(buf));
    printk("buf:%s\n", buf);
    printk("msglen:%d\n",strlen(msg));
    printk("msg:%s\n", msg);
    return len;
}
```

I found the msg's len is 0, and the buf and msg can't be shown on console.
[The screenshot without strlen(buf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTJte.png)

But when I add the code "printk("buflen:%d",strlen(buf));",I found the msglen is 5, and I can see buf on the console buf still can't see msg. Here is the code(I just add one line):

```
    printk("buflen:%d\n",strlen(buf));
    printk("buf:%s\n", buf);
    printk("msglen:%d\n",strlen(msg));
    printk("msg:%s\n", msg);
```

And this is the things on the console:
[[The screenshot with strlen(buf)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnOZB.png)

So I am confused with these two things:

1.why I can't see msg on the console

2.Why the msg len is 5(which is argv1's len) when I add strlen(buf)

Here is the test code iam.c:

```
#define __LIBRARY__
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_syscall1(int, iam, const char*, name);
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    iam(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank for your help sincerely!

Comment: This seems like a question about programming. Printk seems to be in use still. bTW, a quick search for printk indicates it prints to the kernel log, not the console...

Comment: It prints to the console as well (but the console is often not visible).